# How to stop a soundfont MusicDeviceMIDIEvent from completing on iOS

Tags: ios, core-audio, midi, soundfont

I've an app that successfully uses the AUSamplerGraph to play soundfont sounds.

The main sound is guitar.

If a 'lower' note on the same string is played, I stop the previous note from playing through.
The default behaviour is like plucking a string and it rings until it dies out.

Sending a note off event, and the sound still tapers off.
Sending a note on with a volume of 0, and the sound still tapers off.

```
UInt32 onVelocity = loudness;
UInt32 noteCommand = kMIDIMessage_NoteOn << 4 | 0;

OSStatus osStatus;

osStatus = MusicDeviceMIDIEvent(self.samplerUnitGuitar, noteCommand, noteNbr, onVelocity, 0);
```

Tried quite a few things. The mode approach didn't appear to work. doesn't look like the AUSampler implements that control.
     AudioUnitReset // did the trick.

Comment: Did some digging. Appears [Mode 4 - Omni Off / Mono](http://www.philrees.co.uk/articles/midimode.htm) is the way to go. next step is to try it out.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify, you want to stop the note's decay after you send Note Off?

To my knowledge, the only way to do this is to send a Control/Mode Change message with [All Sound Off](http://www.blitter.com/~russtopia/MIDI/~jglatt/tech/midispec/sndoff.htm). Unfortunately, this will kill ANY notes that are currently playing on that channel. (And MusicDevice AudioUnits only respond to one channel.) But it works.

```
UInt8 kMIDIMessage_ControlModeChange = 0xB0;
UInt8 kMIDIMessage_ControlTypeAllSoundOff = 0x78;

MusicDeviceMIDIEvent(sampler, kMIDIMessage_ControlModeChange, kMIDIMessage_ControlTypeAllSoundOff, 0, 0);
```